# Checkbox Undefined index error in Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am getting some errors when trying to create a checkbox within a simple plugin I am creating.
I have a simple settings page at the moment.
The errors are:

> Illegal string offset 'single_images'

And

> Undefined index: single_images_zoom

Here is the checkbox code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input id="iwmp_settings['single_images']" name="iwmp_settings['single_images']" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked(1, $iwmp_options['single_images'], false); ?> />
<label class="description" for="iwmp_settings['single_images']"><?php _e('Use with Single Images', 'iwmp_domain'); ?></label>



<input id="iwmp_settings['single_images_zoom']" name="iwmp_settings['single_images_zoom']" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked(1, $iwmp_options['single_images_zoom'], false); ?> />
                    <label class="description" for="iwmp_settings['single_images_zoom']"><?php _e('Use Zoom effect with Single Images', 'iwmp_domain'); ?></label>
```

The Illegal string offset issue seems to be caused from this snippet:

```
<?php checked(1, $iwmp_options['single_images'], false); ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put quotes around the index for HTML names - otherwise you end up with `'single_images'` (including single quotes) as the PHP name (so you'd have to address it `$iwmp_options["'single_images'"]`, which some might consider confusing) ... eg:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function () {
    register_setting( 'iwmp_settings', 'iwmp_settings' );

    add_settings_section( 'single_images', __( 'Single Images', 'iwmp_domain' ) , function () {
        $iwmp_options = get_option( 'iwmp_settings' );
        // Note quotes around the PHP index, no quotes around the HTML index.
        // (Also id's should basically be alphanumeric with underscores/hyphens (for pre-HTML5 compatibility anyway).)
        ?>
        <input id="iwmp_settings_single_images_" name="iwmp_settings[single_images]" type="checkbox" <?php checked( isset( $iwmp_options['single_images'] ) ); ?> />
        <label class="description" for="iwmp_settings_single_images_"><?php _e('Use with Single Images', 'iwmp_domain'); ?></label>
        <br />
        <input id="iwmp_settings_single_images_zoom_" name="iwmp_settings[single_images_zoom]" type="checkbox" <?php checked( isset( $iwmp_options['single_images_zoom'] ) ); ?> />
        <label class="description" for="iwmp_settings_single_images_zoom_"><?php _e('Use Zoom effect with Single Images', 'iwmp_domain'); ?></label>
        <?php
    }, 'iwmp_settings' );
} );

add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    add_options_page( __( 'IWMP Settings', 'iwmp_domain' ), __( 'IWMP', 'iwmp_domain' ), 'manage_options', 'iwmp_settings', function() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2><?php _e( 'IWMP Settings', 'iwmp_domain' ); ?></h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php settings_fields( 'iwmp_settings' ); ?>
                <?php do_settings_sections( 'iwmp_settings' ); ?>
                <p class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Changes', 'iwmp_domain' ) ?>" />
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    } );
} );
```

Also, just checking for `isset()` here on checkbox values makes things simple. And if you want to manipulate them then set a variable eg `$single_images = isset( $iwmp_options['single_images'] );` etc. or use a wrapper function. (And as a side note for shortcode compatibility I find `1/0` handier then `true/false`.)